# TPM or usb startup error on Acer C720 Chromebook

Tags: usb, startup, chromebook, tpm

I'm pretty new to Linux and have had Ubuntu 16.10 installed on my c720 Chromebook for a while now but recently it doesn't want to start up properly, giving me these errors and putting me into emergency mode:

```
tpm tpm0: [firmware bug] Tpm interrupt not working, polling instead
usb 2-4: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
/dev/sda1: recovering journal
/dev/sda1: clean, 262146/850304 files, 3078446/3400448 blocks
```

I have had this problem before but decided to just reinstall Ubuntu. At first, this seemed to have solved the problem but it reappeared after a while. I have tried deactivating the TPM but that doesn't seem to make a difference (Maybe I did it wrong?). All help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you do it ?  Please post those steps

Comment: Deactivating the TPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have run into the same issue install 14.04 upgrade it to 16.04 then upgrade again to 16.10. Yes I know this takes a lot of time but it works. Alternatively you could use chrome os and install crouton and install xfce4 distro of ubuntu

Comment: Thanks very much. I will try the upgrade method as reinstalling chrome os would be almost more complicated and I don't use it anyway.

Comment: There is a guide by Dave Bennett on installing ubuntu on a chrome book. It is the c720 model and it is a very good guide for anyone